# Is there a way to enter data at non-leaf levels in iccube?

Tags: olap, iccube

I'm looking to evaluate iccube as an embedded OLAP server.  Before doing so, is it possible to enter data at non-leaf levels?  If not natively, is there a workaround?  This is one of the major requirements.  Also, what are the different methods to enter data?  Is there an Excel interface option?

Thanks.

Regards,
Gerd

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, Check the link type in the measure group definition.

[image]

You can also decide if a hierarchy does not do a parent/child aggregation. Meaning that by default the parent includes all child data. This is in the hierarchy definition ( Fact Aggr. Type ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  From your example above, say I have 3 levels on Customer and Product dimensions.  Is it possible to load Sales Target on level 2 on each dimension (top down)?

Comment: Yes, select in the combobox 'Intermediate Level' or 'List of Levels'